# Using k-means, I got a error ; array with 0 feature

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to cluster my csv data, using matplotlib and k-means.

My csv data is about energy consumption.
https://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge/blob/master/challenge2/data/total_watt.csv

I want to cluster the values per day into 3 groups: low, medium, and high energy consumption.

This is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans



MY_FILE='total_watt.csv'
date = []
consumption = []


df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
df = df.resample('1D', how='sum')


for row in df:
    if len(row) ==2 :
        date.append(row[0])
        consumption.append(row[1])


import datetime
for x in range(len(date)):
    date[x]=datetime.datetime.strptime(date[x], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

X = np.array([date, consumption])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["b.","g.","r."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)

plt.show()
```

But when I implemented this code, I got a following error;

```
(DataVizProj)Soma-Suzuki:Soma Suzuki$ python 4.clusters.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4.clusters.py", line 31, in <module>
    kmeans.fit(X)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 785, in fit
    X = self._check_fit_data(X)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 755, in _check_fit_data
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 367, in check_array
    % (n_features, shape_repr, ensure_min_features))
ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(2, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

How can I cluster my csv data properly.??

EDIT-----------------------------------------------------

This is my new code. Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans



MY_FILE='total_watt.csv'
date = []
consumption = []


df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
df = df.resample('1D', how='sum')
df = df.dropna()

date = df.index.tolist()
consumption = df[df.columns[0]].values



X = np.array([date, consumption])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["b.","g.","r."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)

plt.show()
```

and new error...

```
(DataVizProj)Soma-Suzuki:Soma Suzuki$ python 4.clusters.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4.clusters.py", line 26, in <module>
    kmeans.fit(X)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 785, in fit
    X = self._check_fit_data(X)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 755, in _check_fit_data
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 344, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

EDITED2-----------------------------------------

Thank you Jianxun!!

I finally succeeded o cluster my csv data!!
Thank you so much!!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans



MY_FILE='total_watt.csv'
date = []
consumption = []


df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
df = df.resample('1D', how='sum')
df = df.dropna()

date = df.index.tolist()
date = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in date]
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()
date_numeric = encoder.fit_transform(date)
consumption = df[df.columns[0]].values

X = np.array([date_numeric, consumption]).T




kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["b.","r.","g."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)

plt.show()
```

[image]
But as you can see, the x-axis does not reflect time, although we set it properly....

Comment: If you want to visualize the consumption distribution, you should consider using an histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem:

```
for row in df:
    if len(row) ==2 :
        date.append(row[0])
        consumption.append(row[1])
```

This will give you unexpected empty list `date` and `consumption` because `for row in df` actually loops over columns instead of row, and that's precisely why you've seen the error message saying that it has no features.

Also, I've seen there are two `NaN` in consumption, so you need to `df = df.dropna()` (or impute these missing values) because `sklearn` is not `NaN` tolerant.

To get data from your dataframe, you can write something like this

```
date = df.index.tolist()
consumption = df[df.columns[0]].values
```

Next, you've already parsed the date in `pd.read_csv`, so the following part of your code will not work at all.

```
import datetime
for x in range(len(date)):
    date[x]=datetime.datetime.strptime(date[x], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Finally, just feeding the raw `date` with `consumption` into `KMeans` won't produce too much useful results. You should consider convert `date` into numeric data, for example, dummies for dayofweek.

To use `LabelEncoder`:

```
date = df.index.tolist()

date = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in date]

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()
date_numeric = encoder.fit_transform(date)

# feed date_numeric with consumption into your KMeans
# must use .T to transpose your X, sklearn think each column is a feature
X = np.array([date_numeric, consumption]).T
```

for your plotting issue:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

colors = ["b.","r.","g."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",encoder.inverse_transform(X[i,0].astype(int)), X[i,1], "label:", labels[i])
    ax.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)
a = np.arange(0, len(X), 5)
ax.set_xticks(a)
ax.set_xticklabels(encoder.inverse_transform(a.astype(int)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I just fixed my code!! But I still get another error...
I edited my question. It would be great if you could check it!!

And also, thank you for advising"You should consider convert date into numeric data, for example, dummies for dayofweek." but I have to cluster the values per day into 3 groups: low, medium, and high energy consumptio....

Comment: @SuzukiSoma The new error is because the `date` is a `datetime` object, and `sklearn` only accept numeric or string data. (you can see this in the last line of the error message). If you wish to convert `date` to string object, use this code `date = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in date]`

Comment: It says....
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2011-04-18
But I think "'%Y-%m-%d'" is correct..

Comment: @SuzukiSoma That brings back to the previous question: how do you interpret this `date` data? If you treat it as string, then you need to first use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` to convert those text data into numeric form. Since all your dates are distinct, it's equivalent to replace `date` with `np.arange(len(date))`.

Comment: @SuzukiSoma I've added how to use `LabelEncoder` to my post.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! 
I finally succeeded to cluster my csv data, but the x-axia does not reflect time, as you can see on my question (I edited)

Comment: @SuzukiSoma just updated my post. please give a look. :-)

Comment: OMG.. It worked!! Thank you very much! 
From now, I try to understand it!! 
Thank you very much!!!